# Сделать появление блока плавным

Tags: javascript

как сделать применение нового класса плавным?

```js
    var main_menu_block1 = document.getElementById("main_menu_block1");
    var main_menu_block2 = document.getElementById("main_menu_block2");
    var main_menu_block3 = document.getElementById("main_menu_block3");
    var mmb_left1 = document.getElementById("mmb_left1");
    var mmb_left2 = document.getElementById("mmb_left2");
    var mmb_left3 = document.getElementById("mmb_left3");
    var mmb_right1 = document.getElementById("mmb_right1");
    var mmb_right2 = document.getElementById("mmb_right2");
    var mmb_right3 = document.getElementById("mmb_right3");
    window.onload = function() {
main_menu_block1.onclick = function() {
    mmb_right1.className += " show";
    mmb_left1.className += " show";
    mmb_right3.className -= " show";
    mmb_left3.className -= " show";
    mmb_right2.className -= " show";
    mmb_left2.className -= " show";
    mmb_right2.className += " hide";
    mmb_left2.className += " hide";
    mmb_right3.className += " hide";
    mmb_left3.className += " hide";
}
main_menu_block2.onclick = function() {
    mmb_right2.className += " show";
    mmb_left2.className += " show";
    mmb_right1.className -= " show";
    mmb_left1.className -= " show";
    mmb_right3.className -= " show";
    mmb_left3.className -= " show";
    mmb_right1.className += " hide";
    mmb_left1.className += " hide";
    mmb_right3.className += " hide";
    mmb_left3.className += " hide";
}
main_menu_block3.onclick = function() {
    mmb_right3.className += " show";
    mmb_left3.className += " show";
    mmb_right1.className -= " show";
    mmb_left1.className -= " show";
    mmb_right2.className -= " show";
    mmb_left2.className -= " show";
    mmb_right1.className += " hide";
    mmb_left1.className += " hide";
    mmb_right2.className += " hide";
    mmb_left2.className += " hide";
}
}
```

```css
#mmb_left1, #mmb_left2, #mmb_left3, #mmb_right1, #mmb_right2, #mmb_right3 {
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
}
.mmb_left {
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 display: none;
 p {
  opacity: 0;
 }
}
.mmb_right {
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 display: none;
 p {
  opacity: 0;
 }
}
.hide {
 opacity: 0;
 display: none;
 p {
  opacity: 0;
 }
}
.show {
    -webkit-transition: 0.7s;
   -moz-transition: 0.7s;
   -ms-transition: 0.7s;
   -o-transition: 0.7s;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 opacity: 1;
 background-color: black;
 display: inline-block;
 p {
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
 }
}
hr {
 margin: 0;
}
body {
   background-color: #7a9273;
   margin: 0;
}
.main {

 &_blog {
  background-color: #7b88bf;
  float: left;
  &_smm {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  a {
     text-decoration: none;
  }
    .roboto;
  }
 }
 &_menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #bc5b55;
  z-index: 110;
  &_block {
   position: relative;
   cursor: pointer;
   height: 12%;
   min-height: 50px;
   max-height: 70px;
   padding-top: 10px;
   p {
    .roboto;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
   }
   h2 {
    .roboto;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size: 18px;
   }
   h3 {
    .roboto;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
   }
   a {
    .roboto;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="main_menu">
    <div id="main_menu_block1" class="main_menu_block main_menu_nk"><h2>Накрутка</h2>
        <div class="mmb_left" id="mmb_left1"><p>231212</p></div>
        <div class="mmb_right" id="mmb_right1"><p>231212</p></div>
    </div>

    <hr>
    <div id="main_menu_block2" class="main_menu_block main_menu_p"><h2>Продвижение</h2>
        <div class="mmb_left" id="mmb_left2"><p>231212</p></div>
        <div class="mmb_right" id="mmb_right2"><p>231212</p></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="main_menu_block3" class="main_menu_block main_menu_vs"><h2>Ведение страницы</h2>
        <div class="mmb_left" id="mmb_left3"><p>123</p></div>
        <div class="mmb_right" id="mmb_right3"><p>123</p></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: а зачем все так запутанно сделайте хотя бы один класс этим элементам которые выполняют одну функцию

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том что свойство display анимировать нельзя! В целом код правильный. Если сделать сразу display: block или другой и анимировать только opacity, то будет нормально, а если вы хотите чтоб выезжали блоки, то можете анимировать height с 0 до нужного значения. НО снова таки, нельзя анимировать от 0 до auto, нужно до значения, при этом любого как % так и px em rem.

Answer (score 0):

вот это свойство попробуйте присвоить по умолчанию тем блока которым надо применить анимацию

```
div {
   transition-duration: .2s;
}
```

[тут посмотреть `Использование CSS переходов` на **MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)
[и тут `CSS3-переходы` на **HTML5 BOOK**](https://html5book.ru/css3-transition/)